# How to mount a sub-app in Express 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

in *sub-app-dir/**app.js***

Express **2**:

```
app.mounted(function (parent) {
  this.helpers({masterviews: parent._locals.settings.views + '/'});
});
```

Express **3**:

*app.mounted* and *app.helpers* are no longer supported.
As suggested in the migration guide, ***app.helpers*** could be replaced by *app.locals* but no documentation is provided for migrating *app.mounted*.

Comment: are you looking for something like [Modular web applications with Node.js and Express - Video on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/56166857)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you want to do, but I'd do it like this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , mysubapp = require('./lib/mysubapp/index'); // path is just for example
var app = express();

// then you mount the app
app.use(mysubapp);
// or if mysubapp returns a function
app.use(mysubapp());
```